# Performance bottleneck in expect script

Tags: performance, shell, sed, expect

I'm trying to find out the point in my script that is slowing down my entire process. I'm using the expect script to send a sed command to search and replace a line in a file. This takes anywhere from 2s to 20s to finish, when it shouldn't last more than a second. I am two expect scripts in parallel in two terminals. The first file, `launchmpj.exp` launches a qsub job that takes several seconds to start. The second file, `launchneuron.exp` waits for the qsub job to start and continues the script. When the qsub job starts, the `launchmpj.exp` sends a command that allows the second file, `launchneuron.exp` to know the qsub job started and to stop waiting.

Here's `launchmpj.exp`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn ssh $::env(username)@server
expect "$ " 
send "qsub -I -q berger -A lc_tb -l nodes=\$nbnodes -l walltime=24:00:00 -d .\r"
expect "$ "
send "cp \$PBS_NODEFILE node`sed -n '1p' nodequeue`\r"
expect "$ "
send "sed -i '/wait=on/ s//wait=off/' `sed -n '1p' qsubwaitqueue`\r"
expect "$ "
send "cd $::env(MPJ_HOME)/bin\r"
expect "$ "
send "sh $::env(MPJLAUNCH)\r"
expect "Process 6 ended"
```

Here is the second file `launchneuron.exp`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn ssh $::env(username)@server
expect "$ " 
send "set qsubwait = qsub`sed -n '\$p' queue`.sh\r"
expect "$ "
send "sh \$qsubwait\r"
expect "$ " 
send "set nodefile = node`sed -n '1p' nodequeue`\r"
expect "$ "
send "ssh `sed -n '2'p \$nodefile`\r"
expect "$ "
send "cd $::env(NEURON_HOME)\r"
expect "$ " 
send "nrniv -python $::env(NEURONPY)\r"
expect "$ "
```

As part of the process, I'm running a `sed` substitution on the file below. The execution of `sed` alone is very fast, which means it's not the bottleneck in the aforementioned script. However, when done from the expect script, that's when it takes a long time.

```
sed -i '/wait=on/ s//wait=off/' qsubwait.sh
```

File `qsubwait.sh`:

```
wait=on
echo "Waiting for qsub to start."
while [ $wait = on ]; do
eval `sed -n '1'p qsubwait.sh`
echo `sed -n '1'p qsubwait.sh`
done
```

Comment: How exactly are you running this command? (was the `send` part of your command?) Even though you could simply replace, instead of search separately first, it shouldn't take so long to perform the substitutions. In fact, what do you mean by *sending the command*? If you're running this through some network connection, it seems to be very clear where the problem is.

Comment: I was running the command through an expect script. 
But I don't think this is relevant since the command has clearly been executed in the terminal after the "command has been sent."

This is especially clear when the subsequent expect script lines have already started executing for 20 seconds before the sed command completes.

Comment: Then you should try to run `sed` alone, just to check if it takes as long as it does with `expect`. With your sample file, it does not take longer than 0.038s to finish in my machine.

Comment: Could you try to explain a little better what you are actually trying to do here? It seems like a very convoluted way to achieve a simple task; maybe I am missing something subtle. Why for example use the `eval` rather than a direct statement?

Comment: @Rubens Ok, I just tried it with the `sed` alone and it was very fast. So this seems like a culprit with the `expect` script then. Any tips on what I could do about it? 

@Floris Well I'm trying to have a script wait until it receives a signal from another terminal that edits that wait file to turn the wait off. This is one of the first scripts I've written so I'm quite new at this. If you have suggestions on how to do it simply, I'd be very interested.

Comment: @yhelothar I've edited your question, and left a field `<add your script here>` for you to add the script(s) you're trying to execute, with the `expect` calls. Complementing the question, more people will be able to help you -- without seeing the other commands you're running, it is hard to say where the problem actually is.

Comment: Am also experiencing some issue with expect script. When I execute ssh direct to the server it takes me 3 seconds with expect script it takes 30 seconds?

How did you solve your case? May be it will help me as well

Answer (score 0):

Are you hitting expect's timeout value? Run your expect script with `exp_internal 1` to see what expect is waiting for.

Comment: Timeout is set to -1.

The expect script have well continued past sending the sed command and have already been well into executing `send "sh $::env(MPJLAUNCH)\r"`

Despite this, the sed command doesn't successfully do its job until several seconds later.